# Error : reference to withName is ambiguous

Tags: scala, enums

I have two Enums in a package.

One is **Status**.

```
object Status extends Enumeration{

  type Status = Value
  val ACTIVE , INACTIVE  = Value

}
```

And the other is **Type**.

```
object Type extends Enumeration {
type Type = Value
val PAINTING , SCULPTURE , MANUSCRIPT= Value

}
```

I have setter for both of them in **Art** class.

```
 class Art {
//some code

    def setStatus(setStatus: Status) = {
      status = setStatus
    }

    def settype(settype:Type) = {
        type = settype 
      }
    }
```

Now I am trying to set these enums from another class using **withName()** function like this.

```
    class B {
// some code
    val art = new Art
    art.settype(withName("PAINTING"))

    art.setStatus(withName("ACTIVE"))
    }
```

It gives me this error.

> reference to withName is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same
>   scope by import models.ArtModels.Type._ and
>   import models.ArtModels.Status._

Please guide me how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which one you want like this

```
class B {
// some code
  val art = new Art
  art.settype(Type.withName("PAINTING"))
  art.setStatus(Status.withName("ACTIVE"))
}
```

Edit:

If you define your enumerations in another object you can specify it like this

```
object Test extends App{
  // some code
  val art = new Art
  art.settype(Models.Type.withName("PAINTING"))
  art.setStatus(Models.Status.withName("ACTIVE"))
}
```

Comment: Please note `type` is a reserved word in Scala and can't be used as a variable name, unless you use back ticks

Comment: no i have simplified it here in real i am not using "Type", and i have tried like this but it give " not found: value Type" and "not found: value Status" on Type and Status although i have the right imports

Comment: Did you import like this? `import Status._`

Comment: Did you define your enumerations in another object? If so import like this `import Models.Status._`

Comment: if by other object you mean in other package than yes i have the enum and the calling class in different packages and i am already importing  enums as you mentioned , but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The method 'withName' is a function of the 'scala.Enumeration' class. You must explicitly call it from the object instance.

```
class B {    
  // some code
  val art = new Art
  art.setType(Type.withName("PAINTING"))
  art.setStatus(Status.withName("ACTIVE"))
}
```